# How to filter from a grouped Data in Python

Tags: python

How to filter from a grouped dataset in Python

```
s=train['PdDistrict'].value_counts()
print(s)
```

For the above code the output is like this:
SOUTHERN      157182
MISSION       119908

Now i need to filter for the PdDistrict='MISSION' alone while doing the value_counts.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: I assume you use pandas and get the count of values in which `PdDistrict` columns contain `MISSION` string? You need to be a bit more explanatory... Anyway if that is what you want you can use this `train[train['PdDistrict'].str.contains("MISSION")].value_counts()`

Comment: Thanks .
But when i use the above code i received this error

Answer (score 0):

Create a sample dataframe

```
train = pd.DataFrame({
        "A": ["MISSION", "SOUTHERN", "MISSION", "MISSION", "MISSION", "SOUTHERN"],
        "B": [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
    })
```

First assign `s` with dataframe that have column `A` with value `MISSION`

```
s = train[train['A'] == 'MISSION']
```

Then count the value in column `A`

```
s['A'].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
MISSION    4
Name: A, dtype: int64
```