# Filtering on a Grouped and Aggregated Data In Python

Tags: python, pandas

I need to group by one of the variables in the dataframe and then top of the grouped data need to perform some aggregation and filter out values in a new aggregated values.
Below is the code:

```
ee=spend.groupby(["Location"]).agg(
Total_Spend=pd.NamedAgg(column='Actual_PO', aggfunc='sum'),
Total_Vendors= pd.NamedAgg(column='Vendor Name', aggfunc=pd.Series.nunique),
Vendors_On_Contract= pd.NamedAgg(column='Supplier On Contract', aggfunc=pd.Series.nunique),
)

ee.round(decimals=2)
```

above i am grouping on location post which there are 3 calculation Total Spend, Total Vendors and Vendor On Contract.
The vendor on contract has 3 values - Yes, No, NA. I need to filter out what is the count of Vendor on contract ="Yes".The above code gives unique values with all 3 categories.
Researched [Group By Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42993093/how-to-filter-from-a-grouped-data-in-python)  but did not help on what i was looking for.

Comment: @G.Anderson you may misread the question. There's no `Supplier On Contract` column in `ee`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this case you can use a lambda function. Also, you can do named aggregation like this:

```
ee=spend.groupby(["Location"]).agg(
    Total_Spend=('Actual_PO', 'sum'),
    Total_Vendors=('Vendor Name', pd.Series.nunique),
    Vendors_On_Contract=('Supplier On Contract', lambda x: x.eq('Yes').sum()),
)

ee.round(decimals=2)
```

Comment: This really help. though rather than sum i was looking for unique vendor on contract count but i changed in your code and worked. Really appreciate